# I have a stored procedure that is not working for all parameters @AnID

Tags: sql, left-join

The parameter is an ID that is the primary key for the `table1`. The other 3 tables contain details for reference against `table1`. Obviously if I cut out all the joins, I get only data from `Table1`, with any ID. I would really like to understand what is going on. Thanks.

```
SELECT 
    Detail14, Detail15, Detail16, //etc, etc
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Table2 ON dbo.Table1.FK_AnID = dbo.Table2.PK_AnotherID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblTable3 ON dbo.Table2.FK_Group = dbo.tblTable3.PK_RowID 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.tblTable4 ON dbo.tblTable4.Name = dbo.Table1.Named
WHERE 
    PK_RefNumber = @AnID
```

Comment: Just to rule out the stored procedure parameters, does the query return the desired dataset when you execute it alone (outside of a stored procedure)?

Comment: Yeah, if I take out the joins and just run a query on table1, it returns the dataset, but the same paramter, yields nothing with the joins.

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag for the actual, concrete database **system** you're using - whether it be `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2` or something else entirely....

Comment: Have you verified you are joining on the right fields? It sounds like one of your inner joins is not working correctly. If you make them left joins, does the query return only NULLs from those tables?

Comment: First, what table is    PK_RefNumber in?

Comment: The database is MS SQL, and PK_RefNumber is in Table1.

Answer (score 0):

Break this down by doing in steps. Use select * until you have the joins right, then go to the specific fields you want.

So get records for the first table with the where clause (if it is from the first table). Add the second table. If you get records,then that is not the source of the problem and add the third, etc.

Likely you are either joining on the wrong fields or you have an inner join where you need a left join.

Comment: It doesn't get result with changing any of the INNER joins to LEFT, if I change all them to FULL JOINS, i get the result set i need. Sorry if this is the long route but it's a production database, I have exported.

Comment: Are you sure it is a full join you need or did you start with the wrong table for the inner and left joins?  In other words are the null records only on the first table?

Comment: Also works as a FULL JOIN, FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN. all the fileds in the other tables are full of relationship data to descibe the fields in table1. Non of them are empty, but the are all nullable, except their respective Primary Keys.